# Git not found. Install it or configure it using the 'git.path' setting

Tags: git, macos, visual-studio, macos-ventura

Facing error as "Git not found" in VS Code in Mac OS Ventura.

How to resolve this error in VS Code on mac? Any Help is appreciated :)

NOTE: My GIT is working fine in Terminal but only isn’t recognized in VS Code Source Control (3rd Icon in the left bar)

Comment: did you try installing git?

Comment: Note that Apple-Git (the Apple-modified version) is part of the Xcode tools, and is annoyingly installed and removed somewhat unpredictably by various Apple upgraders. You may want to install the Homebrew Git, which is more up to date; it's possible to install both, although then things are a bit confusing.

Comment: @SudirKrishnaaRS why are you reposting your comment in multiple threads? If one of these answers worked for you, mark it as the solution...

Answer (score 20):

Just found this solution and this works :

I have also attached the solution screen recording :
https://youtu.be/vFJCrzlPOow

GIT NOT FOUND ERROR IN VS CODE (Mac OS Ventura)

Step 1: Check if git is installed in your system by running the below command

```
git --version
```

Step 2: Find the path where GIT is installed by running the below command

```
which git
```

Step 3: Open Visual Studio Code,
navigate VS code -> Preferences -> Settings -> Search "git path" in the settings search box -> "Edit in settings.json" (in the first option)

```
"git.path", "paste_your_git_path_here"
```

(Hint: Follow Step 2 to find the path)

This helped solve the VS Code Git not found error!!

Thank You :)

Comment: This answer should be downvoted. The right solution is to install the Command Line Tools for the new version

Comment: No, not necessarily. This solution worked for me. For some reason, after upgrading to Ventura, my git.path variable was missing.

Comment: I also upgraded to Ventura (M1 chip) and `git --version` returned `xcrun: error: invalid active developer path`. Running `xcode-select --install` solved it. Didn't need to do Step 3 in this solution.

Comment: The approach works for me, `which git` did the trick

Comment: "git.path": "/usr/local/bin/git"
helped me

Comment: The command line tools were installed and I had this issue. After running `git -version` it had me accept the new Xcode license agreement (which I had to re-view using `sudo xcodebuild -license`), at which point I didn't need to add "git.path"

Answer (score 13):

You can install git using `xcode-select --install` to install the Apple version, or you can get the upstream one with `brew install git`. Check https://brew.sh or alternatively, https://git-scm.com/downloads.

Comment: After installing Command Line Tools via `xcode-select --install` it still wasn't working. Turns out I had to accept the license before git would work. `which git` returned a valid `/usr/bin/git` however `git --version` prompted me to agree to a license. You can do the license step directly with `sudo xcodebuild -license`. Be careful if you're rapidly paging through the file, as if you hit the wrong key at then end you'll exit and won't be able to agree. Once I agreed to the license terms and reloaded VSCode, it worked.

Answer (score 10):

It is because you need to accept the Xcode license again after installing the update. Resolve this by running：

```
sudo xcodebuild -license accept
```

vscode will get back normal after you accept the license.

Comment: This is probably very common for many developers who have Xcode on their system, even if they don't use Xcode often.  In fact, especially if they don't use Xcode often, since it's easy to forget it's on there. Great suggestion!

Comment: After upgrading to Sonoma and updating Xcode as well, vscode started to complain with `Git not found. Install it or configure it using the 'git.path' setting`.  Typing any `git` command on the terminal confirmed your solution would solve my case, since it complained as well: `You have not agreed to the Xcode and Apple SDKs license. You must agree to the license below in order to use Xcode`. Accepting the license solved it. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

If you run `git -v` you'll get an error message saying that you have not installed `xcode`

This should work: Open your terminal and run `xcode-select --install`

Answer (score 0):

When you have installed git and also the correct version but still vs code is not recognizing then try changing git path from /usr/local/bin/git to /usr/bin/git. This will work.